# Guardar imagenes de laravel con vue en la bd

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, laravel-7

tengo un pequeño problema espero me puedan guiar, yo guardo un array de imagenes (varias imagenes) con laravel, pero a la hora de guardarlas en la base de datos con vue - axios me guarda todos los otros datos menos las imagenes con el id de la propiedad, quisiera saber si me pueden apoyar en este problemita

controlador

```
        if($request->hasfile('images'))
        { 
            $i = 1;
            foreach($request->file('images') as $item_img )
            {  
                
                $img = new Image;
                $ext = $item_img->getClientOriginalExtension(); // getting extension
                $newFile = $properti->id . '-' . time().'-'.$i.'.' .$ext; // changing file name to property id + current time stemp + esxtension.
                $item_img->move('images',$newFile);
                $img->name = $newFile;
                $img->property_id = $properti->id;
                $img->save();
                $i++;
                    
            };
        }
```

input donde recibo las imagenes

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text">Upload</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="custom-file">
                        <input required type="file" class="form-control" name="images[]" placeholder="Imagenes" multiple="multiple" id="imagenes">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

component de vue

```
 },
      actionForm: function(){
        axios.post('/api/properties', {
          antiquity: this.$refs.Step4.selectedAntiquity,
          furnished: this.$refs.Step4.selectedFurnished,
          floor: this.$refs.Step4.selectedFloor,
          name: this.$refs.Step8.name,
          code: this.$refs.Step8.codigo,
          price: this.$refs.Step2.price,
          description: this.$refs.Step8.text,
          departaments: this.$refs.Step6.selected,
          municipalities: this.$refs.Step6.selectedSector,
          type_property: this.$refs.TypePropertier.typePropertie,
          type: this.$refs.Step2.offertype,
          bedrooms: this.$refs.Step3.selectedBedrooms,
          bathrooms: this.$refs.Step3.selectedBathrooms,
          parking: this.$refs.Step3.selectedParking,
          area: this.$refs.Step3.area,
          characteristic: this.$refs.Step5.caracteristicas,
          address: this.$refs.Step6.direccion,
          lat: this.$refs.Step6.lat,
          lng: this.$refs.Step6.lng,
          image: this.$refs.Step7.images,
          reference: this.$refs.Step6.edificio
        }).then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        }).catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
        });
      },
      prevProperties: function (){
        this.pageStep = 8
        this.$refs.PreviewProperties.typePropertie = this.$refs.TypePropertier.selected
        this.$refs.PreviewProperties.offertype = this.$refs.Step2.selected
        this.$refs.PreviewProperties.Sector = this.$refs.Step6.ciudad
        this.$refs.PreviewProperties.code = this.$refs.Step8.codigo
        this.$refs.PreviewProperties.price = this.$refs.Step2.price
        this.$refs.PreviewProperties.Bedrooms = this.$refs.Step3.selectedBedrooms
        this.$refs.PreviewProperties.Bathrooms = this.$refs.Step3.selectedBathrooms
        this.$refs.PreviewProperties.area = this.$refs.Step3.area
        this.$refs.PreviewProperties.descriptions = this.$refs.Step8.text
        this.$refs.PreviewProperties.files = this.$refs.Step7.srcImages
      }
    },
    created: function(){
    }
  }
```

la verdad no entiendo cual es el problema que tengo ya que me guarda los otros datos pero este no..

Comment: Se cumple esta condición `if($request->hasfile('images'))`?

Comment: si mi laravel las guarda bien en la bd, pero el problema es cuando voy a mandar la peticion con el axios